# Use K9 mail as a library, is it possible?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, k-9mail

I'm trying to understand K9 more & test if I can add TTS to it. I have been trying to import it as a module & change it to a library but seems it doesn't work with me once I try to add K9mail to my project. This is the erroe & it is in every value.xml:

```
Error:(3414) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ShowcaseView.Light'.
Error:(3415, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'sv_backgroundColor'.
Error:(3414) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ShowcaseView.Light'.
Error:(3415, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'sv_backgroundColor'.
```

I have been deleting them since yesterday but they seem endless!
Is it possible? How? tons of errors are shown in the gradle & manifest..

Comment: Please share what you've tried and what some of those errors are

Comment: Sorry @cricket_007, I have added the most annoying ones

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `ShowcaseView` library.